# remove multiple checked values using jquery

Tags: php, jquery

Please, i have this code here which helps me to extract a few rows from my database into a grid.

Now i have this select all option.
Here is the function:

```
function removeUser(){
    var row = $('#dg').datagrid('getSelected');
    if (row){
        $.messager.confirm('Confirm','Are you sure you want to remove this user?',function(r){
            if (r){
                $.post('remove_er.php',{id:row.id},function(result){
                    if (result.success){
                        $('#dg').datagrid('reload');    // reload the user data
                    } else {
                        $.messager.show({   // show error message
                    title: 'Error',
                    msg: result.msg
                        });
                    }
                },'json');
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And the php:

```
$id = intval($_REQUEST['id']);
$sql = "delete from rbpos_epos where id=$id";
$result = @mysql_query($sql);
```

Where do i have to modify in order to delete all the selected rows?
For the moment even though i have selected all, i still can delete just one record..

Thanks..

Comment: are you getting any error?

Comment: No Suresh, i don't get any error, i just can't get it to work..

Comment: FYI suppressing PHP errors with `@` is a bad practice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After researching `.datagrid()` a bit, it looks like you might need something from the bottom of [this](http://www.jeasyui.com/tutorial/datagrid/datagrid3.php).

**EXCERPT:**

```
var ids = [];  
var rows = $('#tt').datagrid('getSelections');  
for(var i=0; i<rows.length; i++){  
    ids.push(rows[i].itemid);  
}  
alert(ids.join('\n'));
```

Specifically notice **`datagrid('getSelections')`** and then the loop to iterate through all results.

**EDIT:** Adding some more specific help...

```
function removeUser(){
    var rows = $('#dg').datagrid('getSelections');
    $.messager.confirm('Confirm','Are you sure you want to remove this user?',function(r){
        if (r){
            for(var i=0; i<rows.length; i++) {        
                    $.post('remove_er.php',{id:rows[i].id},function(result){
                        if (!result.success){
                            $.messager.show({   // show error message
                                title: 'Error',
                                msg: result.msg
                            });
                        }
                    },'json');
            }
            $('#dg').datagrid('reload');    // reload the user data only once after deleting selected objects
        }
    });
}
```

Code is not tested, but the concept is there. This method should be sufficient for a dozen or so objects at a time, but if you are looking to delete more than that you could overload the web server. This method issues an ajax call for each checked element.

Comment: Thanks,  it is very helpful :), could you please help me on how to pass this info and use it in the remove function?

Comment: Worked and like a charm :):):):):):):)
Thank you, so so much!

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
$ids = is_array($_REQUEST['id'])?$_REQUEST['id']:array($_REQUEST["id");
$ids = array_map("intval", $ids);
$sql = "delete from rbpos_epos where id in (".implode(",",$ids).")";
$result = @mysql_query($sql);
```

Comment: You need to make sure that the field names that you have defined are in array notion for multiple checkboxes ie.  `name="id[]"`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are only acting on the first element of your selected list.

You need to iterate through each of your rows, and can either issue the delete $.post() for each one, or combine a string builder with Orangepill's solution to delete them all in one call.

I'm not familiar with the ".datagrid()" method, perhaps the returned object has a ".each()" method, or a ".next()" method to iterate over all of the rows?